# Can I take a volume snapshot with the k8s python client?

Tags: python, kubernetes

In python k8s client, i use below code

yaml file

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
    name: test-snapshot
    namespace: test
spec:
    volumeSnapshotClassName: snapshotclass
source:
    persistentVolumeClaimName: test-pvc
```

python code

```
res = utils.create_from_dict(k8s_client, yaml_file)
```

However, i got this message:

```
AttributeError: module 'kubernetes.client' has no attribute 'SnapshotStorageV1Api'
```

I want to take a volumesnapshot in k8s.
How can i do that?

Please give me some advices!

Comment: If you could add the whole code snippet it would be easier to reproduce. Also, have you seen this github issue comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1195#issuecomment-699510580?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed in part of the comment I made under the question:

> Have you seen this github issue comment: [github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/…](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1195#issuecomment-699510580)?

The link posted in the comments is a github issue for:

- `VolumeSnapshot`,
- `VolumeSnapshotClass`,
- `VolumeSnapshotContent`

support in the Kubernetes python client.

Citing the comment made in this github issue by user @roycaihw that explains a way how you can make a snapshot:

> It looks like those APIs are CRDs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshot-classes/#the-volumesnapshotclass-resource
>
> If that's the case, you could use the CustomObject API to send requests to those APIs once they are installed. Example: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/custom_object.py
>
> -- *[Github.com: Kubernetes client: Python: Issues: 1995: Issue comment: 2](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1195#issuecomment-662190528)*

---

#### Example

An example of a Python code that would make a `VolumeSnapshot` is following:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config


def main():
    config.load_kube_config()

    api = client.CustomObjectsApi()

    # it's my custom resource defined as Dict
    my_resource = {
        "apiVersion": "snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1beta1",
        "kind": "VolumeSnapshot",
        "metadata": {"name": "python-snapshot"},
        "spec": {
            "volumeSnapshotClassName": "example-snapshot-class",
            "source": {"persistentVolumeClaimName": "example-pvc"}
                }
    }

    # create the resource
    api.create_namespaced_custom_object(
        group="snapshot.storage.k8s.io",
        version="v1beta1",
        namespace="default",
        plural="volumesnapshots",
        body=my_resource,
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Please change the values inside of this code to support your particular setup (i.e. `apiVersion`, `.metadata.name`, `.metadata.namespace`, etc.).**

> A side note!
>
> This Python code was tested with `GKE` and it's `gce-pd-csi-driver`.

After running this code the `VolumeSnapshot` should be created:

- `$ kubectl get volumesnapshots`

```sh
NAME               AGE
python-snapshot    19m
```

- `$ kubectl get volumesnapshotcontents`

```sh
NAME                                               AGE
snapcontent-71380980-6d91-45dc-ab13-4b9f42f7e7f2   19m
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes client: Python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Storage: Volume snapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/)*

Comment: Yes Thank you for nice reply.

Comment: It's very useful!